# Multi Carousel with multi cards Angular

Tags: angular, service, slider, singleton, carousel

I have several hotel cards that have slider Carousel, but only the first card's carousel works, when I click the other card's indicator , still first card's carousel working[as you can see,i have ngFor and all cards are from generated from array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KN5q.png)

[you can also see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrEBa.jpg)

I think the problem is single instance but no idea how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Probably all carousel requires unique id (all dom elements should always have unique id!). try to use index and modify id with this index to acquire unique ids.